# C# print stars pattern

Tags: c#

I want to print pattern like

[image: pattern]

but i have a problem with output.

my code is:

```
int i, j, k;

for (i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
{
    for (j = 5; j > i; j--)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }

    for (k = 1; k < (i * 2); k++)
    {
        Console.Write("*_");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `Console.Write("*_");`  All your stars will always have the underscore behind it.  You have to account for the last star.

Comment: Why do you have `k < (i * 2)`? On the first iteration, `i * 2 == 10`. That's way more stars than you want.

Answer (score 5):

There are just a couple of issues:

1. You're writing `"*_"` for every iteration, including the last. Instead, we should only write `"*"` on every iteration, followed by `"_"` on every iteration *except the last one*. We can do this with two different `Console.Write` calls, where the second one checks to see if our iterator is at the last position.
2. You're iterating twice as many times as you need to when you do `k < (i * 2)` (on the first iteration, `i == 5`, so `i * 2 == 10`, which means we'll iterate `9` times). We can fix this by changing it to `k <= i`
3. As a side note, we can declare our loop variables locally in the `for` loops. This reduces their scope, which is usually a good thing.

For example:

```
for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
{
    for (int j = 5; j > i; j--)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }

    for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
        if (k < i) Console.Write("_");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

---

The code can be simplified a little bit if we use the `string` constructor that takes in a character and a number of times to repeat it to write our spaces, and if we iterate one less time in our inner loop we can write `"*_"` followed by a `WriteLine("*")`:

```
for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
{
    // Write (5 - i) spaces at once
    Console.Write(new string(' ', 5 - i));  

    // Write 'i' count of "*", joined with a "_"
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("_", Enumerable.Repeat("*", i)));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: For fun, you can eliminate your inner for-loop and last star with just `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("_", Enumerable.Repeat("*", i)));`

Comment: Ooh...I like that one @LarsTech!

Comment: @LarsTech Good one! Added it! :)

Answer (score 0):

So many ways to do this...here's another one using StringBuilder and a slight cheat by getting rid of the last "_" with Trim().  It's written generically to take the desired number of rows:

```
public static void Main()
{
    StarPattern(7);            
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Quit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void StarPattern(int numberStarsInTopRow)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int row=0; row<numberStarsInTopRow; row++)
    {
        sb.Clear();
        sb.Append(new string(' ', row));
        for(int stars=0; stars<(numberStarsInTopRow-row); stars++)
        {
            sb.Append("*_");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString().TrimEnd('_'));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
*_*_*_*_*_*_*

 *_*_*_*_*_*

  *_*_*_*_*

   *_*_*_*

    *_*_*

     *_*

      *

Press Enter to Quit...
```

Here's a compact version using the trick posted in the comments by LarsTech:

```
public static void Main()
{
    StarPattern(7);            
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Quit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void StarPattern(int numberStarsInTopRow)
{
    for(int row=0; row<numberStarsInTopRow; row++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', row) + String.Join("_", Enumerable.Repeat("*", numberStarsInTopRow - row)) + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```